# LINQ to XML - selecting XML to a strongly typed object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a number of related issues but I will break the questions down into seperate posts.

My XML is `<Person>.....<Skills><Skill>Resus<Skill></Skills></Person>`

My code is :

```
var products1 = from prd in xDoc.Descendants("Person") 

select new BusinessEntityLayer.Personnel
{
  PayrollNo = (String)prd.Element("PayrollNumber"),
  FirstName = (String)prd.Element("Name"),
  LastName = (String)prd.Element("Surname"),
  StreetAddress = (String)prd.Element("StreetAddress"),
  Suburb = (String)prd.Element("Suburb"),
  HomePhone = (String)prd.Element("HomePhone"),
  MobilePhone = (String)prd.Element("MobilePhone"),
  PagerNumber = (String)prd.Element("PagerNumber"),
  Email = (String)prd.Element("Email"),
  RecordType = (String)prd.Element("RecordType"),
  Skills = (List<String>)prd.Element("Skills")
```

My Personnel class is strongly typed. It all works perfectly apart from the Skills collection. Skills is `List<Skill>` but my code won't compile with an error - `XLInq.Element` to `Generic.List`...nor can I use `String[]` (refactoring my business class) as I get the same result.

What strategies do people use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
Skills = prd.Descendants("Skill").Select(e => new Skill(e.Value)).ToList(),
```

Comment: Thanks - that has got me further down the track!

Comment: My integration issue now is that, upstream, I need to supply my XML from a dataset (out of my hands I am afraid!), How do I add a Generic Collection to a Dataset column>?

          dc = new DataColumn("Skills", System.Type.GetType?);
          dtData.Columns.Add(dc);


I am able to derive my XML from ds.GetXML() so am hoping it gets deserialised correctly.If I add it as an object,I get serialisation issues.