# LINQ to XML - select to a strongly typed object (VB)

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

This is not a big issue but it's bugging me. I know how to select into a strongly typed collection (List(Of T), but I can't find a tidy way of doing this for an object that is not a List.

This works:

```
Dim x = From a In response...<artist> _
Select New MBArtistInfo With {.MBID = a.@id, .Name = a.<name>.Value, .Gender = a.<gender>.Value}
Return x(0)
```

but it is annoying to have to do that.

I have seen a C# solution elsewhere along the lines of:

```
var x = from a In response...<artist>
select new MBArtistInfo
{
MBID = etc
```

but I can't convert this to VB.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

Just skip class name:

```
Dim x = From a In response...<artist> _
        Select New With { .MBID = a.@id, .Name = a.<name>.Value, .Gender = a.<gender>.Value }
```

But it will give you `IEnumerable(Of T)`, where `T` is an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx). You should not return objects like that from your methods:

> For example, an anonymous type cannot be used to define a method
>   signature, to declare another variable or field, or in any type
>   declaration. **As a result, anonymous types are not appropriate when you
>   have to share information across methods.**

**Edit**

To get only one element from collection use `First`/`FirstOrDefault` methods:

```
Dim x = (From a In response...<artist> _
        Select New With { .MBID = a.@id, .Name = a.<name>.Value }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but I have to have a strongly typed object to return from my data access layer and I do not want to have to convert from an anonymous type - if it is possible in C# then surely it is also possible in VB

Comment: Anonymous types work the same way in c#. You should show more precise example of c# code you're trying to reproduce in vb.net

Comment: As I said, I am not interested in anonymous types - I need a strong typed object. The C# code I am interested in is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056087/linq-to-xml-selecting-xml-to-a-strongly-typed-object. But I can't convert that to VB.

Comment: You did exactly the same with `Select New ClassName With { .Property = Value }`

Comment: Yes, but what I got was a List (Of MBArtistInfo) - it seemed to me that it should be possible to return a single object rather than having to then refer to the 1st of the collection. But if that is the only way to do it then so be it.

Comment: @JonStranger I've updated my answer. User `First`/`FirstOrDefault`/`Single`/`SingleOrDefault` to get only one element instead of collection.